# Anyone familiar with how ffmpeg handles Out of order MPEGTS packets received on UDP

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, mpeg2-ts

Let us assume an encoder / ffmpeg that is pushing mpegts via udp. And we have another ffmpeg that is receiving these mpegts packets. In receiver end, because media is received over UDP, it is likely that some packets may be lost, or get out of order. I am interested to know how receiving ffmpeg handles it.

Sending process ffmpeg -re -i xyz.mp4 -codec copy -f mpegts udp://localhost:5011

Receiving process -i udp://localhost:5011 output.mov

Comment: FFMpeg manages all of that internally so you need not to worry about it. All you need to do is grab the packets belonging to the streams you wish to decode and ffmpeg will give you the frames back in order. On seeking you will need to tell ffmpeg to flush its internal buffers.

Comment: Yeah WLGfx, That is the expectation. But I was trying to drill down the code of mpegts and avio layer to understand *how* and *where* it does it. Because, if you look at, in MPEGTS, I see continuity counter that could be used. But that is just 4 bit. So, out of order can be absorbed by at most 16 packets. I do not see a definite field that could be used for order, unlike it may be wrapped in RTP, where seq no could be useful and deterministic metric to rely on

Answer (score 2):

A discontinuity in the MPEG2-TS packet headers CC field is almost always only used to indicate lost MPEG2-TS packets on the TS level. The 4 bits of the CC field are just to few to allow reliable handling of out-of-order packets. Also on the transport stream level you either do receive a packet or you don't receive it at all, so handling of out-of-order packets does not regard the transport stream itself.
Reordering only becomes an issue for IP datagrams where in-order reception of IP packets can not be guaranteed. In UDP there is no built-in mechanism to allow reordering of packets. If you want reordering you have to use RTP, either on top of UDP or directly below IP.